# Why does the old Frac() function seem to be ADDING fake precision?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I am using Delphi 11 Community Edition.

I have a number `14587.2541`.  When I apply old tried and true `Frac()` to it, it gives me `0.254100000000108` as the output. If I convert that back to a string with `FloatToStr()`, it gives me the same answer in a string.

Anybody know why `Frac()` wants to add eight `0`s and a `108` on the end?  It has done this consistently across several different programs.

`Frac(14587.2541)` should give me `0.2541` and instead gives me `0.254100000000108`.  I have tried zeroing the variable first, and that does nothing different.

Comment: This is how computers work. There are about 10 000 000 questions on this topic on the www. We don't need one more.

Comment: The problem is not limited to just `Frac()`, this is simply how floating-point numbers work in general. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/). You can reproduce the problem with `var d := 14587.2541; WriteLn(d);` for instance.

Comment: I wouldn't even describe this as being a problem

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/ - What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic (one of several guides online - search for "everything everyone absolutely needs to know about floating point" in Google: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=everything+everyone+absolutely+needs+to+know+about+floating+point to see more)